# Error:error: '__ANDROID_API__' macro redefined [-Werror,-Wmacro-redefined] -Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

I'm getting this error, in a project where I have used below modules of "AndEngine",

1) andEngine
2) andEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension
3) andEngineTexturePackerExtension

Previously(2 - 3 months back), the Project was executing properly. And now, when I tried to execute the code, I'm facing this error.

When I tried to comment the "LOCAL_CFLAGS:= -Werror" line, from "Android.mk" of "andEngine" module then I got the error as below,

```
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ arm  : andenginephysicsbox2dextension <= b2PolygonAndCircleContact.cpp
In file included from <built-in>:346:
<command line>:6:9: warning: '__ANDROID_API__' macro redefined [-Wmacro-redefined]
#define __ANDROID_API__ 14
        ^
<built-in>:338:9: note: previous definition is here
#define __ANDROID_API__ 9
        ^
error: error opening 'C:/Users/.../andEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/release/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/andenginephysicsbox2dextension/Box2D/Dynamics/Contacts/b2PolygonAndCircleContact.o.d': No such file or directory
1 warning and 1 error generated.
make: *** [C:/Users/.../andEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/release/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/andenginephysicsbox2dextension/Box2D/Dynamics/Contacts/b2PolygonAndCircleContact.o] Error 1
```

FYI...
Android Studio : 2.3.3.
NDK : Is up-to-date.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but I question why you are using AndEngine. I used it long ago and liked it, but it is not being maintained as far as I can tell. The last entry in Github was 5 years ago.

Comment: Could be related to the order of the include files, or the modules compilation. Posting your make file may help. The fact that it was compiling in the past means that something did change - perhaps your NDK (you could try with an older one, just to pin-point the problem).

Comment: @AlLelopath , this is an old app which was developed in eclipse, and I have imported into Android studio 2-3 months back for implementing new changes, which are currently live...As the App is complex, changing it from AndEngine to any other platform/Engine would be a difficult task... Any other suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: @yakobom , I'll give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: Does one of your build files (Android.mk or Application.mk probably) have a `-D__ANDROID_API__=9` in it somewhere? It looks like you're getting two definitions on the command line. ndk-build only sets one (probably the 14, since you're on an up to date NDK and it won't let you target 9).

Answer (score 1):

After long research, finally got the solution.

All you got to do is,

1) In the "Android.mk" file of "andEngine", replace the line with "LOCAL_CFLAGS := -Werror" with "LOCAL_CFLAGS := -w". Where, "-Werror" shows warnings as it is an error and "-w" suppresses all the warnings(which are not actual errors) related to "andEngine" and other modules.

2) Kindly clean the project and it should work in most of the cases. In case, you still have some error(s) then follow the step 3.

3) You now have to delete the "jniLibs" folder present in "**andEngine**\src\main\" path(Or the path of folder mention in place of "**andEngine**" in that error)  and recompile the code.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':**andEngine**:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug'.
>   More than one file was found with OS independent path 'lib/x86/libandengine.so'

And thank you all for your comments/suggestions.